# How to get some part of string php?

Tags: php

My string is like this `1/2/3/33/34`.

Now i want to get `3/33/34` only this part,

I am getting so many string in all string `1/2/` this is common n i want to get string after `1/2/` this string

Comment: you want all value which start with 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo substr('1/2/3/33/34',4);
```

That takes out `1/2/` (first four letters of the string)

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/356656)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$aa="1/2/3/33/34";
$aa=str_replace("1/2/","",$aa);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$newstring = str_replace("1/2/", "", "1/2/3/33/34");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
echo str_replace("1/2/","","1/2/3/33/34");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

$a='1/2/3/33/34';

( ($pos=strpos($a,'/3'))!==false || ($pos=strlen($a)) )
  && ($str=substr($a,$pos));

/* now result in $str */

echo $str;

// output: "/3/33/34"
// or empty string "" if no '/3' found

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 echo substr("1/2/3/33/,4);
?>
<?php
echo str_replace("1/2/", "", "1/2/3/33/44"); // outputs Hello Dolly!
?>
```